# Detecting mouseover and making a sound when the mouse is over it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So im setting up a main menu for the program I'm making and I was planning to have a beeping sound for whenever a mouse hovers above a button.
The thing is, I have the button labels on my image already, so i don't really know how i could incorporate this.

```
import math, random, sys
import enum
import pygame, time
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit
from pygame import mixer

#initialising python
pygame.init()
#pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
mixer.init()

#define display
W, H = 1600,900
HW, HH = (W/2), (H/2)
AREA = W * H


#bsound effects
buttonsound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("ButtonSound1.wav") 


#initialising display
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
FPS = 54
progress = 0
background = pygame.Surface(DS.get_size())
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("century gothic",25)


#background image
bg = pygame.image.load("Daytime.jpg").convert()
loadingimg = pygame.image.load("LoadingScreen.png").convert()
pause = pygame.image.load("Pause screen.png").convert()
gameover = pygame.image.load("Game Over.png").convert()
mainmenu = pygame.image.load("Main_Menu4.png").convert()
#mainmenu = pygame.transform.smoothscale(mainmenu, (W,H))
loadingimg = pygame.transform.smoothscale(loadingimg, (W,H))

#define some colours
BLACK = (0,0,0,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255,255)
green = (0,140,0)
grey = (180,180,180)

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Moving1.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving2.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving3.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving4.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving5.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving6.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving7.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving8.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving9.png')]
walkRight = []
for i in walkLeft:
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))


char = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char2 = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char2 = pygame.transform.flip(char2, True, False)

x = 0
y = 500
height = 40
width = 87
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
run = True


# FUNCTIONS
def event_handler():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Button():

    def __init__(self, text, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50, command=None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command

        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(green)

        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        #buttonsound1.play()

        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 15)


        text_image = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        self.image_normal.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        self.image_hovered.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        # you can't use it before `blit` 
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

        self.hovered = False
        #self.clicked = False

    def update(self):

        if self.hovered:
            buttonsound1.play()
        else:
            self.image = self.image_normal

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            buttonsound1.play()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.hovered:
                buttonsound1.play()
                print('Clicked:', self.text)
                if self.command:
                    self.command()


class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    Loading = 0
    Menu = 1
    Settings = 2
    Playing = 3
    GameOver = 4

#set the game state initially.
game_state = GameState.Loading


#LOADING
def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def loading(progress):
    if progress < 100:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(int(progress)) + "%", True, WHITE)
    else:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(100) + "%", True, WHITE)

    DS.blit(text, [50, 660])

def message_to_screen(msh, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = HW, HH + y_displace
    DS.blit(textSurf, textRect)

while (progress/4) < 100:
    event_handler()
    DS.blit(loadingimg, (0,0))
    time_count = (random.randint(1,1))
    increase = random.randint(1,20)
    progress += increase
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 402, 29])
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, grey, [50, 701, 401, 27])
    if (progress/4) > 100:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 401, 28])
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, progress, 28])
    loading(progress/4)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(time_count)

#changing to menu
game_state = GameState.Menu


Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.load("MainMenu.mp3")
Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

def main_menu():
    DS.blit(mainmenu, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    btn1 = Button('Hello', 812.5, 250, 100, 50)
    btn2 = Button('World', 825, 325, 100, 50)
    btn3 = Button('Hello', 825, 450, 100, 50)
    btn4 = Button('World', 825, 575, 100, 50)
    btn5 = Button('World', 825, 675, 100, 50)
    btn6 = Button('Hello', 825, 790, 100, 50)

    while run:
        event_handler()
        btn1.update()
        btn2.update()

        # --- draws ---

        btn1.draw(DS)
        btn2.draw(DS)
        btn3.draw(DS)
        btn4.draw(DS)
        btn5.draw(DS)
        btn6.draw(DS)



    pygame.display.update()

main_menu()
```

This is my whole code and I'm not sure what to do with adding buttons.
My image: https://gyazo.com/ca251495b348ab8cd27f7328c84518e8

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where you have button label - you need only its positon and size `(x,y,width,height)` or its `pygame.Rect` to compare with mouse position.

`Rect` has even function [collidepoint](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to check collision with point and it can be mouse position.

```
if button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
    print("Mouse over button")
```

---

**EDIT:**

It is my code from GitHub with [simple example with hovering button using class Button](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover) which changes color when mouse is over button (hover).  It uses `Rect.coolidepoint` in `Button.handle_event()`. Maybe it can help you.

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANTS === (UPPER_CASE names)

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Button():

    def __init__(self, text, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50, command=None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command

        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(GREEN)

        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hovered.fill(RED)

        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 15)

        text_image = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        self.image_normal.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        self.image_hovered.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        # you can't use it before `blit` 
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

        self.hovered = False
        #self.clicked = False

    def update(self):

        if self.hovered:
            self.image = self.image_hovered
        else:
            self.image = self.image_normal

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.hovered:
                print('Clicked:', self.text)
                if self.command:
                    self.command()


# === FUNCTIONS === (lower_case names)

    # empty

# === MAIN === (lower_case names)

def main():

    # --- init ---

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    is_running = False

    btn1 = Button('Hello', 200, 50, 100, 50)
    btn2 = Button('World', 200, 150, 100, 50)

    # --- mainloop --- (don't change it)

    is_running = True

    while is_running:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            # --- global events ---

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                is_running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    is_running = False

            # --- objects events ---

            btn1.handle_event(event)
            btn2.handle_event(event)

        # --- updates ---

        btn1.update()
        btn2.update()

        # --- draws ---

        screen.fill(BLACK)

        btn1.draw(screen)
        btn2.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

        # --- FPS ---

        clock.tick(25)

    # --- the end ---

    pygame.quit()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

---

**EDIT:** play sound only when mouse hovers over button

```
  if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        previous_value = self.hovered # remeber previus value
        self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) # get new value

        # check both values
        if previous_value is False and self.hovered is True:
              buttonsound1.play()

        # similar play sound when mouse unhovers button
        #if previous_value is True and self.hovered is False:
        #      unhover_sound1.play()
```

Comment: I had to make slight changes to your code like the button making ones since my picture already had the buttons on them, I was just looking to make sound effects when they were hovered on: https://gyazo.com/ca251495b348ab8cd27f7328c84518e8

Comment: if you don't show your code then you can't get solution which works ideally with your code. People can resolve one problem in different ways.

Comment: it seems you already resolved your problem - so you don't have to show code.

Comment: oh no not yet since putting my mouse over doesn't play the sound, I tried to test it and it didn't go to well

Comment: `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:` in `handle_event` in `button` is executed many time and sometimes it assigns `True` to `self.hovered` and sometimes it assigns `False` to `self.hovered` - but you play music in this place everytime. You should play it only when `self.hovered` change value from `False` to `True`